# Stack Overflow Addin for Outlook (Placeholder)

Tags: app, placeholder

This is a placeholder app for now. This add-in will enhance outlook's functionality where in user can search in Stack Overflow and post questions on stack overflow sitting in outlook only.

It will provide a seamless experience of using Stack Overflow from Microsoft Outlook.